# How to use os module to save a jpeg to a cretin path- Using kivy screenshot()

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to use the OS module in python to save a jpeg created by the screenshot() function in Kivy? I am on Android so I want to find a way to make it so that the screenshot() gets saved in /sdcard/Pictures.

If I don't have to use the OS module, how would I do it?

Please use examples and add code snippets that other users and I can use for future reference.

I have been stuck on this issue for a long time.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: read the doc, maybe?

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#WindowBase.screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find a way to make it so that the screenshot() gets saved in /sdcard/Pictures.

The argument to screenshot is the filepath to save at, just write `Window.screenshot('/sdcard/Pictures')`.